# Asynchronous multiple requests 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm writing a Wordpress Plugin that sends requests via WooCommerce API. I need to send multiple GET requests to the API and instead of using a for loop and sending each request one after another, I was looking for a multiple request alternative and came across [this class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/). A single request call via WooCommerce API basically looks like this (i.e. to list all products):

```
$headers = array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
// We may use HTTP Basic Auth for Authentication over HTTPS. 
$options = array(
   'auth' => array( 'ck000', 'cs000' ),
)
$response = Requests::request('https://mysite.xy/wp-json/wc/v3/products', $headers, null, $options);
```

This sends an authorized request (via the `$options` array with a consumer key and consumer secret to access the shop site) and retrieves a list with all products available.
Looking at [Requests::request_multiple](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/Requests/request_multiple/), the method takes in an array of requests and options, with the following description of the parameter `$options`:

> If the $options parameter is specified, individual requests will inherit options from it.

Now let's say I want to send 3 requests for different products (AAA, BBB and CCC):

```
// This is how you should create individual requests for request_multiple method
$req1 = array( 'url' => 'https://mysite.xy/wp-json/wc/v3/product/AAA' );
$req2 = array( 'url' => 'https://mysite.xy/wp-json/wc/v3/product/BBB' );
$req3 = array( 'url' => 'https://mysite.xy/wp-json/wc/v3/product/CCC' );
// Create requests array
$requests = array( $req1, $req2, $req3 );
// Send multiple requests
$responses = Requests::request_multiple( $requests, $options );
```

Each response in `$responses` has status code **401 (Unauthorized Access)**, although each request should inherit the same authentication from the `$options` array.

Is this something I should open an issue about on GitHub or is there something that I'm not fully getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this already is a known [issue](https://github.com/WordPress/Requests/issues/209) on GitHub. Still open and not patched from *May 16, 2016.*
Based on the suggestion from the comments, creating a new `Hooks` instance and registering the hook `curl.before_multi_add` with a callback that sets the `cURL` authentication options should solve the **[401] Unauthorized Access** problem.

```
use WpOrg\Requests\Hooks;

$hooks = new Hooks();
$hooks->register( 'curl.before_multi_add', function( &$curl_subhandle ) {
        // curl_setopt can fail => Still [401] then, so take care of that
        curl_setopt( $curl_subhandle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt( $curl_subhandle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, YOUR_CK . ":" . YOUR_CS );
    });
```

Afterwards, set the following in the `$options` array:

```
$options []= 'hooks' => $hooks;
```